# PHP form redirecting to PHP file itself

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get a contact form working, and I'm being redirected to the PHP file itself, and I'm not sure why. I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. I'd love to be pointed in the right direction. The code is below.

Thanks

HTML:

```
<p id='feedback'><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
        <form id="contact_us" enctype="text/plain" method="post" action="form.php">
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name">
            <br>
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="Company" placeholder="Company Name">
            <br>
            <input class="form_field" type="email" name="Email_Address" placeholder="Email Address">
            <br>
            <textarea class="form_field" rows="10" cols="20" name="Description" wrap="hard" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
            <br>
            <p id="required"><i>Please fill in all the fields*</i></p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $to = 'zack@zfisch.com';
    $subject ='Dropset Work Request';

    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $company = $_POST['Company'];
    $email = $_POST['Email_Address'];
    $message = $_POST['Description'];
    $message = <<<EMAIL

 From: $name

 $message

 Email: $email   

EMAIL;

$header = $subject;

if($_POST) {
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    $feedback = 'Email sent!';
}

?>
```

Comment: Remove `enctype="text/plain"` and this `$header = $subject;` that will fail. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still redirecting to form.php, a blank page, in the browser

Comment: try to echo  $feedback; after  $feedback = 'Email sent!';

Comment: Because the `form.php` echo nothing,  a blank page is the expected result. You shoud redirect to another place by `header` function or echo something at the end of the script.

Comment: Well because you've specified that in the FORM element... Either redirect back or handle the request in the current php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line tells the form what PHP file to send the data to:

```
<form id="contact_us" enctype="text/plain" method="post" action="form.php">
```

In particular, it is this part that sends the data to a particular form:

```
action="form.php"
```

In fact, this is fine. You can process a form in the same PHP file that contains the form. Just put the PHP form processing at the top:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['Email_Address'] && $_POST['Email_Address'] != ''){
        $to = 'zack@zfisch.com';
        $subject ='Dropset Work Request';

        $name = $_POST['Name'];
        $company = $_POST['Company'];
        $email = $_POST['Email_Address'];
        $message = $_POST['Description'];
        $message = <<<EMAIL

        From: $name

        $message

        Email: $email   

EMAIL;

        $header = $subject;

        if($_POST) {
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
        $feedback = 'Email sent!';
        }
    }else{
>?
<p id='feedback'><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
<form id="contact_us" enctype="text/plain" method="post" action="form.php">
    <input class="form_field" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name">
    <br>
    <input class="form_field" type="text" name="Company" placeholder="Company Name">
    <br>
    <input class="form_field" type="email" name="Email_Address" placeholder="Email Address">
    <br>
    <textarea class="form_field" rows="10" cols="20" name="Description" wrap="hard" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
    <br>
    <p id="required"><i>Please fill in all the fields*</i></p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: The spaces before the heredoc's closing identifier shouldn't be there. Theoretically, this will throw a parse error. Heredoc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `enctype="text/plain"` otherwise your code is correct in HTML and try to `echo feedback` variable other way is to write all your code above the HTML like below:

```
     <?php

    if (isset($_POST['Email_Address'] && !empty['Email_Address']){
        $to = 'zack@zfisch.com';
        $subject ='Dropset Work Request';

        $name = $_POST['Name'];
        $company = $_POST['Company'];
        $email = $_POST['Email_Address'];
        $message = $_POST['Description'];
        $message = <<<EMAIL

        From: $name

        $message

        Email: $email   

        $header = $subject;

        if($_POST) {
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
        $feedback = 'Email sent!';
        }
    }else{
>?
<p id='feedback'><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
<form id="contact_us" enctype="text/plain" method="post" action="form.php">
    <input class="form_field" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name">
    <br>
    <input class="form_field" type="text" name="Company" placeholder="Company Name">
    <br>
    <input class="form_field" type="email" name="Email_Address" placeholder="Email Address">
    <br>
    <textarea class="form_field" rows="10" cols="20" name="Description" wrap="hard" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
    <br>
    <p id="required"><i>Please fill in all the fields*</i></p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```